# R Difference with previous column across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this that resulted from a cumsum of variables:

```
id v1  v2   v3
1  4   5    9   
2  1   1    4
```

I I would like to get the difference among columns, such as the dataframe is transformed as:

```
id v1  v2   v3
1  4   1    4   
2  1   0    3
```

So effectively "de-acumulating" the resulting values getting the difference. This is a small example original df is around 150 columns.

Thx!

Comment: you can subtract dataframes if they are the same size. so you can do most of the work with `df[3:4] - df[2:3]` -- just change the indices to suit

Answer (score 0):

```r
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
id v1  v2   v3
1  4   5    9   
2  1   1    4")

x[,c("v1","v2","v3")] <- cbind(x[,"v1"], t(apply(x[,c("v1","v2","v3")], 1, diff)))
x
#   id v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  4  1  4
# 2  2  1  0  3
```

Explanation:

- Up front, a note: when using `apply` on a `data.frame`, it converts the argument to a `matrix`. This means that if you have any `character` columns in the argument passed to `apply`, then the entire matrix will be `character`, likely not what you want. Because of this, it is safer to only select columns you need (and reassign them specifically).
- `apply(.., MARGIN=1, ...)` returns its output in an orientation transposed from what you might expect, so I have to wrap it in `t(...)`.
- I'm using `diff`, which returns a vector of length one shorter than the input, so I'm `cbind`ing the original column to the return from `t(apply(...))`.
- Just as I had to specific about which columns to pass to `apply`, I'm similarly specific about which columns will be replaced by the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for cycle might do the trick, but for larger data it will be slower that other approaches.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), v1 = c(4,1), v2 = c(5,1))
df2 <- df
for(i in 3:ncol(df)){
  df2[,i] <- df[,i] - df[,i-1]
}
```